# Virtual Network Security Group Azure - Opening the ports

Tags: security, powershell, azure, networking, hortonworks-data-platform

I am setting up a Hortonworks Data Platform cluster on Azure. In azure, all the machines of the cluster have the same PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS and unique internal IP address.

On a vm of the cluster if I want to open some port I am adding [end points](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/) for the virutal machine through Azure Management portal. I added port 8080 for a VM in the end point and configured it to be accessible. (And successfully I am able to access the services running on 8080 from a web browser).

For some services which are running on all the nodes of the cluster (for example data node in the case of Hadoop), I could not configure it as they are behind the same public Virtual IP. Learnt that we need to create Network Security groups. I used the azure [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/network-security-groups/) for reference.

Following are the steps and commands executed in PowerShell to open port 50070

**Creating Security Group:**

```
New-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "sectest1-sg" -Location "West Europe"
```

**Adding a rule to the security group to open port 50070:**

```
Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "sectest1-sg" | Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule -Name NNUI -Type Inbound -Priority 100 -Action Allow -SourceAddressPrefix '*' -SourcePortRange '*' -DestinationAddressPrefix '*' -DestinationPortRange "50070" -Protocol TCP
```

**Associating NSG with VM:**

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "clusterServiceName" -Name "VMOnWhichPortNeedsToBeOpened" | Set-AzureNetworkSecurityGroupConfig -NetworkSecurityGroupName "sectest1-sg" | Update-AzureVM
```

In the powershell after finishing execution I see the success messages like:

```
VERBOSE: 7:04:38 PM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment
VERBOSE: 7:04:40 PM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment
VERBOSE: 7:04:40 PM - Begin Operation: Update-AzureVM

OperationDescription                    OperationId                             OperationStatus
--------------------                    -----------                             ---------------
Update-AzureVM                          8587690e-f8ea-0614-ad79-a44615f7cas2    Succeeded

VERBOSE: 7:05:43 PM - Completed Operation: Update-AzureVM
```

However when I try to access the port 50070 **through web portal I see "This webpage is not available" error message**.

I am not sure if I missed here something or something additional needs to be done.
I would be greatful if you could give some helpful suggestions/pointers to solve this issue.

JE